# Is it possible to upgrade PHP in an environment provisioned using puPHPet?

Tags: php, macos, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

If I have a vagrant box provisioned using [puPHPet](https://puphpet.com) on OSX, is it possible to upgrade the PHP version from 5.5 to 5.6 with a simple config file change or do I need to re-provision from scratch?

Alternatively is it simpler to upgrade the PHP via the guest OS package manager, in this case **Ubuntu 14.04**. The use case here is a single development environment (not a large team) but I may later want to provision the same environment for a second developer and/or on a cloud service and would then need the latest stable PHP.

**UPDATE**

I tried editing puphpet/config.yml as suggested:

```
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '56'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: Europe/London
    mod_php: 0
```

And then did `vagrant reload` but `php -v` still shows 5.5.14. I also tried `vagrant reload --provision` and this seemed to do a lot more than just restart the VM (ran through provisioning scripts) but the PHP version has not changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near as I know, this should be easy enough to do.

Adjust the `puphpet/config.yml` to reflect your changes and run `vagrant provision`.

To clarify, in order to upgrade the php version I adjusted:

```
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '54'
```

to

```
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '56'
```

the exact location of this information in the config.yml for me right now is on line 109 through 111. But the file may vary depending on features that may or may not get added so don't rely on that too much.

Comment: I tested it again; you were right. However `vagrant provision` worked for me. I set up a new puphpet box with php 5.4, after vagrant up finished I checked the version on the server, it really was 5.4. I adjusted the version in the config.yml to 5.6 and ran the provision. I ran into an issue with xdebug but this log (http://pastebin.com/ug8DLG5Q) clearly shows 5.6 installed.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add your config.yml changes to your answer?

Comment: I just tried it. It did not work for me. In fact, puphpet installed 5.5.9 despite me selecting 5.4. php -v shows 5.5.9 before and after the provision command. Perhaps it is just not working for Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't think you can do this, it's deeper puppet don't know how to do this.

Nevertheless, you can add a custom script which will do the trick but the best solution for me is to destroy and re-up your VM (which should not be a problem I guess according to vagrant philosophy).

(I tried to delete the /.puphpet-stuff/ directory in the vm as I thought the vagrant will believe this is a clean install after relaunch the vagrant provision but it doesn't work better.)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, after updating in `config.yml` the PHP version from '54' to '56' in a CentOS vagrant box.

`vagrant provision` followed by `vagrant reload` did not work.

`vagrant destroy` followed by `vagrant up` worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade the php version, I had to destroy the VM (`vagrant destroy`) , change the version in `config.yml` and then do a fresh `vagrant up`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me either with `vagrant provision`.
At the end I logged in via SSH and updated php manually.